# New to html so plese help.............,This image in the CSS code is not showing up

Tags: css, html, background-image

```
<div id="image">  

</div>



#image 
{   
    background-image:`url(image.jpg);`  
    background-repeat:no-repeat;    
    background-attachment:fixed;    
    background-position:center; 
}
```

Comment: is the image file in the same folder as the html/css file?

Comment: Remove the back-ticks around the background image URL.

Comment: Image is in the same folder itself and removed the back-ticks, still not working.., this div is inside another div and using IE to open the page...

Comment: remove these things  ` ` from background-image property

Comment: @user3448643 If you have solved your problem you should accept an answer, or if none fit, answer the question yourself with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The property *background-image* has a value between simple quote.
That should be like this:

```
background-image: url('image.jpg');
```

Also check the **image.jpg** and the **your_file.html** are in the same folder.

Comment: The quotes are optional in a URL like this. Double quotes, single quotes or no quotes are all acceptable.

Comment: Sure but in many tutorials and [references](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background-image) this syntax is common.

Comment: Image is in the same folder itself and removed the back-ticks, still not working.., this div is inside another div and using IE to open the page..

Comment: It's common, and it's correct, but this is not the reason the page is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work. Please make sure the path of the file. It should be besides in the webpage.

```
<div id="image">  

</div>

#image 
{   
    background-image:url(image.jpg); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;    
    background-attachment:fixed;    
    background-position:center; 
}
```

Comment: Image is in the same folder itself and removed the back-ticks, still not working.., this div is inside another div and using IE to open the page..

Comment: @user3448643 : [Working DEMO](http://jsbin.com/goquq/1/edit). Div inside a div is not a problem. Please check out the above link. You could understand. Which version of Ie you are using. It might be the problem

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that you're including your CSS in [the proper way](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html)?

If yes, and considering that the `background-image: url('image.jpg');` didn't help, you should post a bit more of code and maybe your folder structure.